# Getting 403 forbidden while curl

Tags: linux, curl

I am trying curl to download a few numbers from this website: https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs#Company-Financial-Statements

When I click on any of the links, it opens correctly and displays the correct results. eg
https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/AAPL?period=quarter&limit=400&apikey=

But when I curl, it gives a 403 forbidden error.

```
curl https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/AAPL?period=quarter&limit=400&apikey=<API Key>

<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

[1]+  Done                    curl https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/AAPL?period=quarter
```

If I re-arrange the curl bit, it gives the values, but the values do not match

```
curl https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/AAPL?apikey=<API Key>&period=quarter&limit=400
```

I am not sure what is happening here.

P.S. You can create an API Key by just creating an account, to test it out. Just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` is interpreted by your shell and sends a process to the background. You can see that the executed command was missing some parameters, it only included `?period=quarter`

Put the URL in single or double quotes to prevent shell interpretation or escape each `&` with a backslash as `\&`:

```
curl 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/balance-sheet-statement/AAPL?period=quarter&limit=400&apikey=<API Key>'
```

Comment: wow, that was simple. thanks